# AWS CLI query filtering oddly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Overall, I am trying to find out which of our SNS topics aren't being used.  So I thought to get a list of SNS topics that are active and subtract that from the full list.  Seems like that is not so easy.  Cloudwatch only reports metrics if there has been activity in the last 6 hours.  But it is all I can find, so I will cron a job to grab the active topics every couple of hours and keep a unique list. (If someone has a better idea, I am all ears).

To that end I am building a query to give me the active topic names at a given time.
First pass looks like this

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --query 'Metrics[*].Dimensions[*].[Name,Value]' --namespace 'AWS/SNS' --metric-name 'NumberOfMessagesPublished'
```

That gets me something like this

```
[
  [
    [
        "TopicName",
        "bogus"
    ]
  ]
]
```

But I only want the topic name really.
So, based on the section "Filtering for specific values" in this AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html) I modified the query to be

```
--query 'Metrics[*].Dimensions[?Name=='TopicName'].[Value]'
```

But all I get back is

```
[
    []
]
```

I can't see any difference between the example and my use case.  But I must be missing something.

Comment: Amazon CloudWatch retains metrics for 15 months. It might be that however you are viewing the list of metrics, they are filtered for the past 6 hours. If you extend the time range, the metrics will be there. For your query, try to use different types of quotes around `TopicName`. It is currently closing the single quote that was opened earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the double quotes instead... same result.   Also, while is stores the data for 15 months, both the console and the CLI will only show topics that have been active in the last 6 hours.   When I started this project, I got only three topics.  Then one of our alarms went off, and the topic the alarm sends to started showing up in both console and the first example.  And it had all it's old data.  So they basically hide them if nothing happens for 6 hours.  I couldn't find a way to unhide them.  The only option to list-metrics related is --recently-active which will reduce to 3 hours

Comment: In the Amazon CloudWatch management console, when viewing metrics with the "Metrics" option, there is a time-range selector in the top-right (`1h 3h 12h 1d 3d 1w custom`) that can be used to change the amount of data being viewed. Use **Custom** to change to view all the data. When using `recently-active`, you can [specify a duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) such as `P6M` for the past 6 months. Please note that `list-metrics` only returns the _names_ of available metrics. If you want the actual data you can you use `get-metric-data` (which is rather difficult to use).

Comment: The SNS metrics won't even show up in cloudwatch if it is considered inactive... so you can't choose a timerange.  And the recently-active option only takes one value according to the docs... "specify this parameter with a value of PT3H . This is the only valid value for this parameter" which is 3 hours.

Comment: If you just want to get the value and not the label i.e. TopicName, this command should work `aws cloudwatch list-metrics --query 'Metrics[*].Dimensions[*].Value' --namespace 'AWS/SNS' --metric-name 'NumberOfMessagesPublished'`

Comment: Doesn't that assume that topicname is the only attribute under dimension?  Is that actually true?  I just assumed there could be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider changing

`--query 'Metrics[*].Dimensions[?Name=='TopicName'].[Value]'`

to

`` --query 'Metrics[*].Dimensions[?Name==`TopicName`].[Value]' ``

The difference is the backtick around the comparison value.  Neither AWS documentation or jmespath documentation makes this obvious, though the examples show the backtick. I originally thought it was a MS substitution.

Comment: sweet.  That was the issue.  thanks